# How to notify backend server about auto renew - flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I’m making the use of in-app purchase (the subscription based) in flutter app and for the backend, I’m using Firebase

On the first purchase from the user which happened inside the app, so I can easily listen to the purchase stream and add the expiration date in the Firebase backend on successful payment status

But as you know, the subscription is recurring based, it would automatically renew next month, so how to notify about this event to the Firebase backend, so I can update the expiration date

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    loadPlans();

    InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream.listen((event) {
      for (var element in event) {
        if(element.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased){ // executed on successful purchase
          widget.userModel.expirationDate = DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 30)); // add 30 days from the today day
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(widget.firebaseUser.uid).update(widget.userModel.toMap());
        }
      }
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Google Play Billing API and the pub/sub service to be notified about purchase events. The Google Play Billing team has written a sample demoing how this works here : https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/ClassyTaxiServer

It's advised to use the Play Billing API as it's more secure and instantly notifies your backend of billing events so you can clawback entitlements.